# Is there an SQL way of getting the last rows data and increment/decrement it by 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this `table`

```sql
id | user_id | warns
1  | 84327832 | 0
2  | 89432943 | 2
```

I want a `MySQL` query that does that.

My `SQL` query is this:

```
REPLACE INTO warns (first_name, last_name, username, user_id, warns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Is there a way to get the last number of warns (like 0) and then increment it?

I'm using a `REPLACE` statement which is `INSERT` if the doesn't exist or `UPDATE` if it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery

```
REPLACE INTO warns (first_name, last_name, username, user_id, warns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, (SELECT MAX(warns) + 1  FROM warns) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET warns = warns + 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.warns < t1.warns);
```